# Подменить ядро в установщике

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

Мой ноутбук не совместим с ядром Linux новее, чем 4.9.0(возможно, чуть выше, но не суть).
Я выяснил это опытным путём, пытаясь запустить установку разных дистрибутивов и искал решение возникающих проблем, но не суть.

Таким образом, у меня работает Debian 9. Я пытался обновиться до десятого, но возникли проблемы. Я хотел бы провести чистую установку Debian или Ubuntu последнего выпуска, но всё упирается в версию ядра. Отсюда вопрос — есть ли возможность подменить ядро на установочном носителе ядром нужной версии?

Comment: вот эта добавка: *и какими проблемами это может обернуться?* — лишняя. благодаря её наличию вопрос сразу классифицируется как «слишком общий»/«зависит от мнения» и подлежит закрытию. чтобы исправить текст вопроса, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: по сути вопроса: 1. «у меня работает Debian», 2. «хотел бы провести чистую установку Debian» — вместе пункты лишены смысла. просто [обновитесь до нужной версии](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.ru.html). это ж вам не убунта какая-нибудь, или, простите за выражение, ms/windows, которые, чем чаще переустанавливаешь, тем «лучше».

Comment: ну а если всё-таки «очень надо», то вот инструкция: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html.ru#usb-copy-flexible

Comment: Я пробовал обновляться. Это привело к проблемам с зависимостями и отвалу Plasma, Xorg и прочего.

Comment: перечислим факты: 1. у вас «проблемное» железо. 2. стабильный выпуск debian gnu/linux работает стабильно. 3. попытка присоединиться к разработке тестируемого выпуска закончилась неудачей (и, возможно, отправкой баг-репортов). // что делать? 1. если надо работать, продолжайте работать. 2. если хотите продолжить тестирование, продолжайте: тестировщиков никогда много не бывает. конечно, не ленитесь слать баг-репорты — это поможет сделать дистрибутив лучше.

Comment: 10 вроде анстейбл - гляньте модель проца в поддерживаемом списке.

Comment: Надо работать, но хочется иметь систему с актуальными пакетами в репозиториях. А по причине проблемного железа, я не могу поставить ту же, например, Ubuntu.